# C# How to verify if the position is empty in a jagged array?

Tags: c#, arrays, jagged-arrays

So, i need to make this structure

Positions:

0 - {2, 5, 7, 8}

1 - {9, 10, 12}

2 - {3, 4}

3 -

I'm trying to do it using jagged arrays (i don't know if i have a better way to do that, maybe using ArrayList or Hashset but i'm not sure).

So, to insert the numbers in the jagged array, i'll receive user input (2 numbers). If the user type 1 and 2, i need to insert both in the jagged array.

But to do that, I need to check if the Position 0 is empty, and if it's empty, i need to put the user input in the jagged array. If it's NOT empty, then it'll check if the input exists on the jagged array.

So, the problem i'm having is to check if the jagged array is empty.

I tried this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Digite a lista de numeros com um espaço de diferença entre cada numero");
        string[] ar_temp = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
        int[] ar = Array.ConvertAll(ar_temp, Int32.Parse);
        int tam = ar.Length;
        char fim = 's';


        int[][] jaggedarray = new int[tam / 2][];


        for (int x = 0; x < tam / 2; x++)
        {
            jaggedarray[x] = new int[tam];
        }

        if (jaggedarray[0] is null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("is null");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("isn't null");
        }
    }
```

But i get the wrong output (it doesn't recognize the position as null, even with an empty array there...)

How can i check if the positions of the jagged arrays are empty ?

Comment: Sounds like maybe you want an array of `List<int>`.

Comment: `jaggedarray[0] is null`? Is this even legal C#?

Comment: @WiktorZychla this won't compile with `is null`.

Comment: @SamvelPetrosov: I know that, this was a question to the OP.

Comment: @WiktorZychla I just clarified

Comment: It's compiling with this code.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn yeah maybe it's better using that approach, but i'll still need to have a list for each position, and check if this list is empty, and add values to that list... i didn't found out how to do that.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn
It's possible to use a simple array and put a List<int> inside of the array ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace `is null` with `== null` like this:

```
int[][] jaggedarray = new int[tam / 2][];

for(int x = 0; x < tam/2; x++)
{
    jaggedarray[x] = new int[tam];
}

if (jaggedarray[0] == null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("é nulo");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Não é nulo");
}
```

Comment: still doesn't work. it's entering in the else condition.

Comment: i understood the problem now ... the problem was because i was initializing the structure inside the array before using it. Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 1):

Empty array isn't null. You have to check array length:

```
if (jaggedarray[0] == null || jaggedarray[0].Length == 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("é nulo");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Não é nulo");
}
```

Also, you can simplify your code:

```
Console.WriteLine(jaggedarray[0] == null || jaggedarray[0].Length == 0 ? "é nulo" : "Não é nulo");
```

Comment: it's not working. it's returning me the size of the array inside position...

I mean, i need to specify a size to each array inside the jagged array to compile. So, each array have a size of 4. That verification is returning 4. I'll edit the question with the full code for better understanding.

Comment: If you will always initialize it, then you need some List of flags to determine if  jaggedarray[i]  was changed or not. Also, i fixed my answer a little bit.

Comment: it's possible to use the jagged array without initialize it ?

Comment: Yes, initialize array itself, but don't initialize jaggedarray[x] before you need it.